# A double integral with one known value of the integrated function.

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I have a double integral that has the following form:
$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \int\limits_0^\pi\mu(\theta) \exp(\tau\sec(\theta)) p(\theta, \phi) B(\theta, \phi) \,d\theta\,d\phi$

I know that the part 
$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{\pi} B(\theta, \phi) \,d\theta\,d\phi$
is equal to, let us say $0.5$.

Is there a way to take the part $\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{\pi}B(\theta, \phi) \,d\theta\,d\phi$ from the first equation? I can't treat it like a constant, right? I mean like this
$0.5 \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \int\limits_0^\pi\mu(\theta) \exp(\tau\sec(\theta)) p(\theta, \phi) \,d\theta\,d\phi$

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: @Robert Thnk you Robert. Do you have an idea, how could this work? I mean, how can I get rid of the double integration of $B(...)$ if I already know the result?

Comment: You usually can't, especially if you care about the exact value that it equals (if you only care about an upper bound, Cauchy's or Holder's Inequality might help). The entire expression $\mu\exp pB$ might offer some approach. You might be able to change the order of integration. You might be able to use change of variables. We would need more context.